# Illegal start of simple expression in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax

I just start learning scala. I got an error "illegal start of simple expression" in eclipse while trying to implement a recursive function:

```
def foo(total: Int, nums: List[Int]): 
  if(total % nums.sorted.head != 0)
    0
  else 
    recur(total, nums.sorted.reverse, 0)

def recur(total: Int, nums: List[Int], index: Int): Int =
  var sum = 0 // ***** This line complained "illegal start of simple expression"
              // ... other codes unrelated to the question. A return value is included.
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong about defining a variable inside a (recursive) function? I did a search online but can't one explains this error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A variable declaration (`var`) doesn't return a value, so you need to return a value somehow, here's how the code could look like:

```
object Main {

  def foo(total: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {

    if (total % coins.sorted.head != 0)
      0
    else
      recur(total, coins.sorted.reverse, 0)

    def recur(total: Int, coins: List[Int], index: Int): Int = {
      var sum = 0
      sum
    }

  }


}
```

Comment: this is the most important point to remember while using scala. Assignments will return ```Unit```

Answer (score 2):

The indentation seems to imply that `recur` is inside `count`, but since you did not place `{` and `}` surrounding it, `count` is just the if-else, and `recur` is just the `var` (which is illegal -- you have to return something).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I was doing something like

```
nums.map(num =>
  val anotherNum = num + 1
  anotherNum
)
```

and the way to fix it was to add curly braces:

```
nums.map { num =>
  val anotherNum = num + 1
  anotherNum
}
```

I thought these expressions were equivalent in Scala, but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Found  example 8.1 in the book that looked like:

```
object LongLines {

def processFile(filename: String, width: Int) **{**
  val source = Source.fromFile(filename)
  for (line <- source.getLines) 
    processLine(filename, width, line)
**}**
```

Note: the "def processFile(filename: String, width: Int) {" and ending "}"

I surrounded the 'method' body with {} and scala compiled it with no error messages.