# How to save the output of the match statement into variable?

Tags: scala

I have an piece of code where i have used the pattern matching inside it i have used map in all cases, i want to get the output of what map is giving to a variable. Below is my code:

```
override def run():List[Option[Student]] =
StudentDataCache.get(surname) match {
  case Some(i) => i.otherSiblings.map(siblings =>
    StudentDataCache.get(siblings) match {
      case Some(i) => Some(i)
      case None=> getStudentFromDatabase(siblings)
    }
  )
  case None =>
    getStudentFromDatabase(surname).get.otherSiblings.map(siblings => StudentDataCache.get(siblings) match {
        case Some(i) => Some(i)
        case None=> getStudentFromDatabase(siblings)
      }
    )
}
```

output of both the map statement inside case is List[Option[Student]], is there a way to get this into variable because i want to convert this list into a single object since HystrixCommand execute output does not supports List as output. I want to convert it to StudentListing(val listing: List[Option[Student]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just... assign it to a value / variable:

```
override def run(): StudentListing = {
  val result = StudentDataCache.get(surname) match { /* same code*/ }
  StudentListing(result) // or however you wrap it into a StudentListing...
}
```

A match expression, *like any other expression in Scala*, is evaluated into a value - you can do whatever you want with this value.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Error:(44, 3) illegal start of simple expression
  val result = StudentDataCache.get(surname) match {
  ^

Comment: Did you add the `{` at the end of previous line, to make this into a multi-line implementation of `run` instead of a single line? See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962563/illegal-start-of-simple-expression-in-scala